# Como grifar texto num autocomplete jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, css, autocompletar

Estou usando o autocomplete do jQuery e gostaria de sublinhar dentro do resultado o texto que está sendo procurado, procurei alguns exemplos na web, mas só achei com plug-in, como este:

[Exemplo](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/artigos/30-plugins-de-jquery-e-ajax-para-autocomplete)

Tentei trazer o texto formatado do `php` com as tags `html` (`<b>texto</b>`), mas o autocomplete entende de forma literal mostrando as tags, deve ser por questão de segurança e eu concordo :)

Tem como fazer de forma nativa com o jQuery?

Codigo exemplo:

```
    $("#pesquisax").autocomplete({
        dataType: "json",
        minLength: 3,
        autoFocus: true,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/solicitacao/solicitacao.localizar.nome",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {'term': request.term},
                        success: function (json) {
                            response(json);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }).autocomplete("widget").addClass("autocomplete");
```

Comment: Coloque a parte relenvante do código que tem sff. Principalmente a parte que faz o autocomplete

Comment: No link que você passou, [tem um exemplo usando jquery](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)  é só mudar a classe `.autocomplete-suggestions strong {
    color: #18324f;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: underline;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Solução:

```
        open: function (event, ul) {
            $('.ui-autocomplete li').each(function () {
                var texto = $(this).html().toUpperCase();
                var busca = $("#pesquisax").val().toUpperCase();
                var troca = texto.replace(busca, "<b>" + busca + "</b>");
                $(this).html(troca);
            });
        }
```

Acrescentar o evento **open** e tratar cada linha da lista.

Exemplo completo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pesquisax").autocomplete({
    source: ["MARCELO", "ROBERTO", "RICARDO", "MARCIA", "MARCIO", "HELENA", "HELENI"],
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $('.ui-autocomplete li').each(function() {
        var texto = $(this).html().toUpperCase();
        var busca = $("#pesquisax").val().toUpperCase();
        var troca = texto.replace(busca, "<b>" + busca + "</b>");
        $(this).html(troca);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pesquisax" value="" placeholder="Digite MAR">
```